# Implicit recommender Tuning hyper parameters Pyspark

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, implicit

computeMAPK function takes the model, Actual data and Validation data (user,product) to generate ratings. Then sort the predicted ratings for every user and take top K to compare with the actual data to calculate Mean Average Precision at K

I am using this function to tune the hyper parameters i.e. fit multiple models and select the best Lambda, Alpha, Ranks with highest MAPK. This works for small data sets but when the the matrix becomes 10 Million users * 200 products. It breaks especially with reduceByKey step and joins. Any better way to Tune the hyper parameters for ALS implicit ? and I am using Spark 1.3.

Actual RDD is of the form (user,product)
Valid RDD is of the form (user,product)

```
def apk(act_pred):
      predicted = act_pred[0]
      actual = act_pred[1]
      k = act_pred[2]
      if len(predicted)>k:
          predicted = predicted[:k]
      score =0.0
      num_hits = 0.0

      for i,p in enumerate(predicted):
            if p in actual and p not in predicted[:i]:
                      num_hits += 1.0
                      score += num_hits / (i+1.0)

      if not actual:
          return 1.0

      #return num_hits
      return (score/min(len(actual),k))



def computeMAPKR(model,actual,valid,k):
    pred = model.predictAll(valid).map(lambda x:(x[0],[(x[1],x[2])])).cache()
    gp = pred.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)
    #gp = pred.groupByKey().map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))


    # for every user, sort the items by predicted ratings and get user, item pairs
    def f(x): 
        s = sorted(x,key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
        sm = map(lambda x:x[0],s)
        return sm

    sp = gp.mapValues(f)



    # actual data
    ac = actual.map(lambda x:(x[0],[(x[1])]))

    #gac = ac.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:(x,y)).map(lambda x : (x[0], list(x[1])))
    gac = ac.reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y)

    ap = sp.join(gac)


    apk_result = ap.map(lambda x:(x[0],(x[1][0],x[1][1],k))).mapValues(apk)
    mapk = apk_result.map(lambda x :x[1]).reduce(add) / ap.count()

    #print(apk_result.collect()) 
    return mapk
```

Comment: You have some issues with the indentation - please fix

Comment: Hi Tom, reformatted and updated the code as well.

Comment: Ash, did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Yes, I increased the cluster size and using Scala with Spark 2.0. I see pretty good performance with Data frames and used the Spark implementation for  MAP.https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#ranking-systems

Comment: The reason I wasn't going to use the MAP function provided by Spark was because you can't give it a parameter of "k". However, I think I can just use the average precision @ k and then take the mean across those results...